# How to send a property as a string in RestEasy response?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws, resteasy

I have a class called Product which has a property called id of type long. Below is the class

```
public class Product {
    private long id;
}
```

The value of id is beyond the value which javascript can handle. I realized this after seeing the below link

[Parse json in javascript - long numbers get rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689790/parse-json-in-javascript-long-numbers-get-rounded)

I dont want to declare the field as String in the domain class. But I want to say to RestEasy that it has to send the value as a string in the json response.

How can I do this? I dont want to use any third party api. Is it possible in RestEasy. I have gone through the documentation but did not find any such annotation or may be I did not go through the documentation properly.

Can anyone please help. Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) as JSON Serializer you can extend the JacksonJsonProvider:

```
@Provider
public class JsonProvider extends org.codehaus.jackson.JacksonJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = locateMapper(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true);
    }

}
```

If you are using [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) you can [register a custom XmlAdapter](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-package-level):

```
public class LongAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Long> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Long id) throws Exception {
        if (id == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return id.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Long unmarshal(String id) throws Exception {
        return Long.parseLong(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: We are not using Jackson api. Unfortunately we are not supposed to use even. Is there any other way?

Comment: Which JSON-Serializer do you use?

Comment: We use jettison serializer

Comment: Thank you. I will check this. Meanwhile I added another method in my domain class which will return id as string. So there will be two methods in my domain class. `getId` and `getIdAsLong`. The first one will be used by jettison and second one will be used by the services/classes in my application. I assumed that jettison will serialize the properties and send only id in the json. But it has sent idAsLong also in the json. But this is not a problem for me. And I will now introduce the jettison XmlAdapter which seems to be a very convincing solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Just add `@XmlTransient` to `getIdAsLong` and Jettison should skip this field.

Comment: I tried the `XmlAdapter` but I received id as long only in the json. I included a `package-info.java` class in the same package where my domain class is. The adapter class is `JobIdAdapter` which extends `XmlAdapter<String, Long>`. I use jboss eap 6.x. Should I do any more configurations in some jboss xml files? Besides my domain class is not annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. Is it necessary to do so?

Comment: There should be no other configuration necessary but you need to annotate your Bean with `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: I annotated the bean with `@XmlRootElement`. Its not working. Later I followed this http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html where package-info.java is not necessary. But still its not working. Even `@XmlTransient` did not work. One thing I noticed is the domain classes are packaged in a jar(ejb) module. Should they be packed in war module for serialization to happen properly? May be I will create a dummy project and check.

Comment: Please check if you really use Jettison. JBoss EAP 6 ships with Jackson afaik. You can change this with adding `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider` or `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider` to your classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57130/discussion-between-krishna-chaitanya-and-lefloh).