# JSON.parse parses / converts big numbers incorrectly and always round value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I receive this string from an API id_post in int:

```
1080281724263649280
```

When I'm using JSON.parse, i receive:

```
1080281724263649300
```

why value not same and always rounded at last 3 digits?

and why in localhost correct value, but in server not correct value?

please help big thanks before

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689790/parse-json-in-javascript-long-numbers-get-rounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your number is too big:

```js
var x = `{ "z" : 1080281724263649280 }`
var y = 1080281724263649280;

console.log(
  JSON.parse(x)
)
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
console.log(y)

// -------------------------------------

// A workaround: Convert to string before parsing
x = x.replace(/:\s+(\d{15,})/g,`: "$1"`)

// or using ES6 syntax which I find unnecessarily verbose here
// x = x.replace(/:\s+(?<num>\d{15,})/g,`: "$<num>"`)

console.log(
  JSON.parse(x)
)
```

Comment: thanks @mplungjan, but i don't have any access in API, i only receive id_post, what can i do?

Comment: See my updated snippet

Comment: You may be safer with the new regex I posted. that includes the colon